# Difference between - and -- (single and double dash) in npm commands

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

Am wondering if this question is already addressed or not.

I have used few commands like this :

```
npm install -g

npm install -d
```

Then i have used few like :

```
npm install XYZ --save-dev

npm install --only=dev
```

Whats the fundamental difference between `-` and `--` ?

Has it got to do anything with primary and secondary arguments ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it's simply that by convention, *nix command line switches that are only one dash (-d) are only one character.  Those with two dashes (--save) are multiple characters long.  Both are optional.

Answer (score 8):

See https://serverfault.com/questions/387935/whats-the-difference-betwen-the-single-dash-and-double-dash-flags-on-shell-comm

Basically, a single dash means that the following flags are single-character only, and generally means that more than one flag can be passed. See all other command line tools:

```
ls -la
grep -inr "asd" .
```

etc

The double dash connotes a single positional flag/argument to a command line tool.

Answer (score 5):

Generally, `-` is an abbreviation, there must be a corresponding `-—` full name.

For example:

`npm install -D` is equal to `npm install --save-dev`

[image: npm install arguments examples]